# Best way to count the number of pdf files in Github Enterprise repositories

Tags: github, github-api, github-enterprise

I am looking for a way to count the number of PDF files in all repositories existing in a self hosted github server ([Github Enterprise](https://github.com/enterprise)). I've got the idea of iterating over all the repositories, [list](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-repository-content) the existing files and count but I'm not sure if this is the best idea. What would be the recommended way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Github API code search](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code) using :

https://api.github.com/search/code?q=extension:pdf%20repo:google/language-resources

or for enterprise :

```
http(s)://[hostname]/api/v3/search/code?q=extension:pdf%20repo:org/repo-name
```

A repository or organization must be specified when using the query, so you could make one request per repository :

- get the [full list of repository](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.21/user/rest/reference/repos#list-public-repositories)
- for each one, execute `http(s)://[hostname]/api/v3/search/code?q=extension:pdf%20repo:org/repo-name`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe this solution would be very time consuming as it requires iterating over all the repositories of a self hosted Github Enterprise and it is considered as my last shot. I even checked GitHub GraphQL API v4 but I didn't found any positive results.